# Neo4j Cypher - String to Integer

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here the value in property r.weight is a string. i have tried following possibilities to convert it into a integer,

```
INT(r.weight)
Integer.parseInt(r.weight)
convert(INT,r.weight)
```

but nothing works. Is there a proper function to do so?

`reduce(total = 0, r in relationships(p): total + INT(r.weight))`

Note : Its not a possible duplicate of [Gremlin type conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314048/neo4j-convert-node-attribute-storage-from-string-to-number)

Version : 1.9.5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985133/neo4j-cypher-toint-function/22038374#22038374

Comment: There are toInt() and toFloat() functions.. But they will be released in 2.0.2 version

Comment: @SumeetSharma , but i m using 1.9.5, is there any help for this version

Comment: Check this function- https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/functions/scalar/#functions-tointeger

Answer (score 13):

In Cypher 3.3.5 `toInt()` is deprecated, rather use `toInteger()`

i.e. `toInteger(r.weight)` - this works fine

Comment: In the question it is stated that version 1.9.5 is being used.

Answer (score 5):

To extend [chamber5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4203939/chamber5)'s answer.

Presumably you are interested in doing some arithmetic with the weights. An obvious use case is to sum the weights going into a node. For example, in a social network perhaps we are interested in how many messages Ada has received from other nodes (colleagues); with one message increasing the weight of that edge or relationship by one.

Thus we want to MATCH for all relationships of a given type (r) going into a Person node with the name property of "Ada".

```
MATCH ()-[r]->(n:Person {name:"Ada"})
RETURN sum(toInteger(r.weight)) AS total_weights_in;
```

Of course we could look for bidirectional total weights also by adjusting our ASCii art:

```
MATCH ()<-[r]->(n:Person {name:"Ada"})
RETURN sum(toInteger(r.weight)) AS total_weights_in;
```

This work in Neo4j version 3.4.9.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comments above there is no easy way to do this with Cypher in 1.9.x. As a workaround you could use the `neo4j-shell` and use the `gsh` or `jsh` or `eval` command to execute a script that iterates over all relationships and converts the value of `weight` property from String to numeric.